# How to pass data using props in v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I used two vue v-for to make my table card,

but I need multiple similar cards,

so I want to use props to draw it up.

How should I modify the code of NewLearning.vue ?

This is my code

NewLearning.vue [image] [image]

This is the code i want (NewLearning.vue need use props)

NewLearningProcess.vue

```
<div v-for="list in lists" :key="list.name">
  <NewLearning :data="list"></NewLearning>
</div>

<script>
import NewLearning from "../components/Learning/NewLearning";
export default {
  components: {
    NewLearning,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: "title",
      lists: [
        { idx: 1,
          CardTitle: "CardTitle",
          grades: [
            { name: "name1",
              group: [
                { itemname: "itemname1-1",
                  timefinish: "1111",},
                { itemname: "itemname1-2",
                  timefinish: "2222",},],},
            { name: "name2",
              group: [
                { itemname: "itemname2-1",
                  timefinish: "3333",},
                { itemname: "itemname2-2",
                  timefinish: "4444",},
                { itemname: "itemname2-3",
                  timefinish: "5555",},],},],}],};},};
</script>
```

my code looks in the front end [image]

I want it looks (There will be different data below) [image]

Comment: I think you're using v-for in the wrong area. Could you upload a photo of how it looks in the front end?

Comment: @frlzjosh okok~ I have updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wished to used `props`, instead of initializing under `data`, add `props` after that

```js
props: {
  grades: Array
  // or, with a default:
  grades: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => [{ ...}, { ...}]
  }
}
```

Reference: from `LinusBorg` https://forum.vuejs.org/t/define-array-of-objects-for-component-props/43618

Comment: grades is just one of the arrays, I want the array method in NewLearningProcess.vue

Answer (score 0):

Well based on the data you created, that's all you're going to get. If you add another object into your `lists` array, like the one below, you should have the cards you want.

```
lists: [
   { idx: 1,
      CardTitle: "CardTitle",
      grades: [
         { name: "name1",
           group: [
              { itemname: "itemname1-1",
                timefinish: "1111",
              },
              { itemname: "itemname1-2",
                timefinish: "2222",
              },
           ],
         },
         { name: "name2",
            group: [
               { itemname: "itemname2-1",
                 timefinish: "3333",},
               { itemname: "itemname2-2",
                 timefinish: "4444",},
               { itemname: "itemname2-3",
                 timefinish: "5555",},
            ],
         },
      ],
   }
   { idx: 2,
     CardTitle: "CardTitle2 ,
     grades: [
        { name: "name3”,
          group: [
             { itemname: "itemname3-1”,
               timefinish: "1111",},
             { itemname: "itemname3-2”,
               timefinish: "2222",},
          ],
        },
        { name: "name4”,
          group: [
             { itemname: "itemname4-1”,
               timefinish: "3333",},
             { itemname: "itemname4-2”,
               timefinish: "4444",},
             { itemname: "itemname4-3”,
               timefinish: "5555",},
          ],
        },
     ],
   }
]
```